# 5 characters added in the middle of my URL

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

I realise that this might be a VERY obscure question but it's driving me mad, I have 5 extra characters being inserted into the URL while navigating between the pages on my site. (eg. http://track.chhs.nsw.edu.au/UXTWP/userAccount.php?) The UXTWP is being added and I'm not sure where from but it is breaking the navigation randomly.

The site is hosted on goDaddy.
It contains HTML CSS PHP JavaScript and mySQL.
Everything was working well until I added a "fix" in PHP to stop a potential 'hack' that would use an id being passed in the URL to switch the viewed content.
I'm not sure this was the problem but that was the most recent change before the errors started occurring.

this is the [site](http://track.chhs.nsw.edu.au) I also looked to place the code up on phpfiddle but I'm not sure what to add?

```
if(isset($_GET['a'])){
    if(strpos($userRow['sID'], $_GET['a']) !== false) {
        $_SESSION['student']=$_GET['a'];
        $tempArray = db_select("SELECT *  FROM student WHERE sID ='".$_SESSION['student']."'");
        $studentRow = array_shift($tempArray);
        $_SESSION['impactTool'] =$studentRow['impactAssToolID'];
        $SName = $studentRow['sName'];
        $SDOB = $studentRow['dob'];
        $SFormDate = $studentRow['formDate'];
        $prevInf = $studentRow['prevInfo'];
        $famInf = $studentRow['famInfo'];
        $contInf = $studentRow['contextInfo'];
        $impactIDMsg = "?z=".$_SESSION['impactTool'];
        $btnFlag = true;
        }else{
            header("Location:logout.php");
        }
```

The intention is to dump the user back to the login screen via logout if they attempt to access a student's detail that doesn't belong to them.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: nothing in the code provided changes a url

Comment: I don't have any code that directly accesses the URL except standard navigation with HTML a tags and one php constructed a tag <br /> `<ul>`
      `<?php foreach($studentRow as $val){`
      `foreach($val as $row){`
      `echo "<li style='clear:both;'><input type='checkbox' value ='".$row['sID']."' name='removeStudent[]' class='deleteButton'><a href='studentProfile.php?a=".$row['sID']."'> ".$row['sName']."</a></li>";`
      `}`
      `}?>`
     `</ul>`

Comment: its your code adding the characters, so i dont know how we can help with out seing it

Comment: I am happy to accept that it is my code creating the extra characters, but it is creating 5 characters only, placing them between the domain and the page trying to be navigated to. Each page has different php functions connected to them there seems to be a common error across pages with uncommon code?

Comment: Happy to post all or any code to be viewed but don't know where to start

Comment: I can't get to live samples of your bug.  Could it be a redirect?  Where and when are the characters inserted?

Comment: you need to debug to find the code at issue.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys I think I have it sorted!

Comment: Well if I can come back cap in hand once the cache was cleared the error returned :-(

Comment: this is the link to the [index page](http://ideone.com/jb2HEv) and the [DataBase managing file](http://ideone.com/pQlX6f) as a start. on a php viewer.

Comment: @Dagon don't want to be a pain just wondering if you might run your eye over those two files the random letters even turn up if you just enter [track.chhs.nsw.edu.au](http://track.chhs.nsw.edu.au) which lands you on the index page and links to the DB connect page.

Comment: @Progrock the extra characters turn up as you navigate between pages, and sometimes just as you arrive at the index page. My best guess at the moment is that it might be Session related. Sometimes it doesn't occur then it will I can't find a trigger. This morning the extra characters turned up but then disappeared leaving the correct URL. There is a link to the site in the comment above.

Comment: Do links on the site have the characters inserted?  Your link above goes to a page with no outbound links to other pages that I can discover.  So I can't see this in action.

Comment: @Progrock sometimes on arriving a the page the chars are added eg "track.chhs.nsw.edu.au/UXTWP/ " when you only enter the "track.chhs.nsw.edu.au" bit they also turn up when you navigate into the structure of site (there are 5 pages only) and they don't seem to have a trigger other than the page change (but not every time????).

Comment: @Progrock you can register if you like so you can navigate those pages or I have set up a dummy user if that would be easier username 'TestUser' pw: 123456.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this time I think it is fixed!! Thank you so much @Progrock for your persistent testing and ideas. 
The fix:
I have included a blank .htaccess file into the root of the site. 
Now I can navigate through the different pages using the onsite navigation and the browser navigation and I can't create the error anymore.

I'm hoping that this is a permanent fix and my best guess is that it was the browser/server looking for the .htaccess file on particular triggers when not finding it looking to the server generic .htaccess file.

Hope this post helps someone in the future experiencing a similar problem.

Comment: If you can get to the file system, if Apache allows overrides, a .htaccess file will most likely be searched for the directory and parent directories.  Scan your  file system all the way up.  Could there have been a .htaccess file there previously that you have clobbered?  Is this a shared host?  Could another site/script have written a .htaccess file somewhere in the directory tree?  Proceed with caution.

Answer (score -1):

Not an answer, but an observation:

I finally experienced the bug when using curl to view headers:

```
curl -I http://track.chhs.nsw.edu.au
```

Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /TSXbZ/
```

Then shortly after, the same curl call resulted in the desired page without the redirect.  So the bug is inconsistent, as you have said.

If I do a header location redirect in Php code.  Or I use a .htaccess rule to do something similar: A return header reads something like this:

```
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Foo)
```

The absence of an apache server header (for some of your responses) makes me suspicious that a proxy or caching layer may sit in front of your webserver and Php code.

Reading your code, I can't see any obvious reasons for the character insertions.

Notice subsequent differences with the following responses (return headers):

```
3:21% curl -I http://track.chhs.nsw.edu.au       
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /XRjRZ/

3:23% curl -I http://track.chhs.nsw.edu.au
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /

3:24% curl -I http://track.chhs.nsw.edu.au
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /

3:24% curl -I http://track.chhs.nsw.edu.au/index.php
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /index.php

3:24% curl -I http://track.chhs.nsw.edu.au/index.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 02 Dec 2016 15:24:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.23
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=60d307bdc288bf1371dc5e0c8c397cdf; path=/
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html
```

Have you got an esoteric .htaccess, or server config?

Comment: I created a .htaccess file a while ago it didn't correct the problem as wanted so deleted it  and didn't really understand how to implement it. I have no server config file. Could it be residing in the server cache even though I have removed the file? BTW thanks so much for persisting with this problem because I am WAY out of my depth with this one.

Comment: The purpose I had attempted to use .htaccess for was to catch 404 errors and redirect the user to the index.php page.

Comment: Does the IP address match what you expect for your hosting?  When I look up the IP, I'm getting a Go Daddy server.  Could this be an evil proxy/malware?

Comment: Godaddy is the company I use for hosting so it sounds right.  Does the site need a .htaccess file??  could it be that I removed some default file that the server is looking for and when it doesn't find refers to a general one that the server uses if none exists?

Comment: Not sure who down voted this inclusion but I don't feel that was deserving as this information was instrumental in finding the final solution. Sorry @Progrock I up voted it but my low rank doesn't allow it to show.

Comment: Probably down voted because it isn't an answer.  No problem.  I'm not sure if this site is legit, and I don't want to panic you, but your IP is listed here: https://ransomwaretracker.abuse.ch/ip/166.62.10.54/host/starmakersentertainment.com/ .  The symptoms do looks suspicious.

Comment: Not sure what that means? Maybe another customer of goDaddy is using the same server to launch attacks? I am pretty sure that goDaddy are a legit company. Would they be able to sneak into my hosting?  I can't see any random files or activity?

Comment: If you can get to any other hosted files on a shared server, it can work both ways, another site maybe able to write to yours.  Another domain looks compromised (a wordpress site) on the same IP address as yours.  I'd relocate code to a different host as that IP is black listed.